# Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new' when adding angular material

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material

I've a small angular application(v9.1.12) that is working.
I just added angular-material:

`ng add @angular/material`

Then I created an Angular Material module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({

  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

then

I reference it in my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MaterialModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

As soon I add this reference, I get this error in chrome(but it still compiles):

```
platform.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/platform.js (platform.js:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/a11y.js (a11y.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js (core.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/button.js (button.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/material.module.ts (material.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
```

What is the issue?

Comment: as @surendrea kumar said, it is likely a problem with your version of `angular/material`. It is otherwise [working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-button-h4hf8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in the **angular/material** version.please change the version of **angular/material** module.

you can use the below version.

```
npm i @angular/material@9.2.4 --save
```

Comment: That was it. For my understanding and in the future, why did this happens? How should I've known that this version was required?